# Using TZipFile to create a new zip file

Tags: c++, zip, c++builder-xe7

I am attempting to use the TZipFile class to create a new zip file and add some files to it.  I am able to add files to an existing zip file using this code:

```
TZipFile *  zip = new TZipFile();
zip->Open(fileName, zmReadWrite);
zip->Add("C:\\0\\t.txt");
zip->Close();
```

However, I am not sure how I can create a new zip file in code, and then add files to it.  I tried calling `zip->Open` on a non-existent file thinking that maybe that would create the archive, however that just caused an access violation.

Comment: Try opening it with just `zmWrite` rather than `zmReadWrite` access.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a new zip-file you must choose `zmWrite`.